# TableView overlaps with top of simulator screen (eg Carrier & Time)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

When i updated to xcode 5.0, my slide out menu seemed to interfere with the default header.

when i scroll up and down on this menu, the title and menu items run over the two header items. should this be happening? will it be the same on a physical device?

See image at this link:

http://postimg.org/image/rxlgxbr6h/

I have tried adding an extra cell, navigation bar etc but nothing seems to stop this problem.

What i am looking to achieve here is for the menu to scroll under these header items.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you add the UITableView to your view ? Are you adding tableview programmatically ?

Comment: It was a drag and drop, i am using storyboards. heres what it looks like in the storyboard file http://postimg.org/image/oel9modut/  is this relevant?

Comment: I have this problem partially solved. see - http://postimg.org/image/gq1seh12l/  however i need it to be black in accordance with the one to the right of the picture. none of the suggested answers shows how to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how iOS 7 works. See this document
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1
Depending on enabled or not autolayout feature you should update your controller to extend additional 20px for status bar.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first iOS app. I do not have autolayout enabled, how would i extend the view by 20px?

Comment: In storyboard/XIB there is new Delta section in dimensions tab. You should properly set there deltaY and deltaHeight for each view except root view in the viewController. Usually you need to set -20 for deltaY  and if view should be resized (eg your tableview) set deltaHeight to 20. And don't forget to setup proper autoresize masks. Just play with it and all be ok.

Comment: I have this problem partially solved. see - http://postimg.org/image/gq1seh12l/  however i need it to be black in accordance with the one to the right of the picture. none of the suggested answers shows how to do this, any ideas?